# get data pair and declare each from json url

Tags: javascript

```
    $url = "https://exchange-api.lcx.com/market/tickers";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
  
  $ADAETHBid = ($json["data"]["bestBid"]);
  $ADAETHASK = ($json["data"]["bestAsk"]);

  $ADAEURBid  = ($json["data"]["bestBid"]);
  $ADAEURASK = ($json["data"]["bestAsk"]);
```

i want get info data
for each pair and declare individualy

ADAEURBid
etc

Comment: that's PHP not javascript

Comment: yes but i want to move on javascript

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can use `fetch()` to retrieve your data and convert it to JSON.

```js
async function init() {
  const url = "https://exchange-api.lcx.com/market/tickers"
  const resp = await fetch(url)
  const json = await resp.json()
  
  const ADAETHBid = json.data['ADA/ETH'].bestBid
  const ADAETHAsk = json.data['ADA/ETH'].bestAsk
  
  const ADAEURBid = json.data['ADA/EUR'].bestBid
  const ADAEURAsk = json.data['ADA/EUR'].bestAsk
  
  console.log("ADA/ETH Best Bid: " + ADAETHBid)
  console.log("ADA/ETH Best Ask: " + ADAETHAsk)
  
  console.log("ADA/EUR Best Bid: " + ADAEURBid)
  console.log("ADA/EUR Best Ask: " + ADAEURAsk)
}

init()
```

Comment: is work, now i need to make 2 file index.html and data.js for run this code on website?

Comment: well, basically yes

Comment: i try to put on index.html